# What is the best way to document an OUTCOME to an answered question?

Tags: discussion

What is the preferred community way of documenting an outcome after applying or trying a particular answer? Sometimes I get some great but different approaches to solve my problem. I'd love to be able to justify why I selected one good answer over another equally qualified one.

I want to do more than just place a bold "updated" in my question, I want to respond to the individual's answer of why this didn't or did solve the issue.

I guess I'm almost asking for an OUTCOME field alongside comments and answers.

Comment: You usually just use comments. "Tried this and it didn't work for x reasons." or "it worked great. I selected this answer over x because of y.".

Comment: upvote the best solution(s) and leave comments if necessary.

Comment: If you think the comparison can be helpful to others with the same question then post it as an answer if it is substantial. Otherwise a comment on why one approach is better than another might be enough.

Comment: So it's not a big deal to post my own answer but mark another correct?

Answer (score 1):

A comment on how the answer worked for you (or not) is not only "nice", but also useful. In many cases, it gives the poster the opportunity to improve the answer, or broaden the possible use of it. It will also make other users understand why you chose the answer and give them the opportunity to decide if the same arguments count for them.

But as mentioned, apart from all that, anyone who answers a question likes to have feedback on the answer in a comment, no matter if the answer is accepted or not. The effort to let know is no doubt appreciated.

I would only post/accept an answer of your own if none of the answers can be developed (together by the poster and you) into an "acceptable" answer.